# Trend analysis on a sample with varying elements - online real estate market

Tags: trend, mean, moving-average

I'm trying to analyze the price trend of an online real estate market, similar to craigslist, over a period of two months on a daily basis.
I collected the data every day, however as every day there are new houses on the market and the ones that are sold are removed what would be the best method to analyze the price trend here?
Would the simple moving average be applicable in this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it is an issue that houses are added/removed?

Comment: @RyanVolpi Not sure, from similar examples that I saw all were on a set with fixed elements. So SMA is ok in this?